# Something is falling off on my plane

Tags: animation

[image]

Hey I need help, I'm not really good at blender but I think I misclicked something that resulted in spheres falling off my plane. How can I disable this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must have created a particle system by accident, just delete it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much